# Stuck on Oracle logic

Tags: sql, oracle

Stuck on bonus question I have.

It asks:

Display department name, city and number of different jobs in each department. 
- If city is null, you should print Not Assigned Yet.
    - This column should have alias City.
Column that shows # of different jobs in a department should have the heading # of Jobs
Limit the width of the City to 25 characters.

The 'department_name' is located in the 'departments' tables.
'city' is located in 'locations'
'job_id' is lcoated in 'employees'

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: if you want some help on this show people what you have tried, the schema, example data and sample of expected results.  Plus this sounds like home work "bonus question"

Answer (score 0):

Table definitions are incomplete but I think you should start from here:

```
    Select 
      d.Department_name, 
      substr(nvl(l.city,'Not Assigned Yet'), 1,25) as "City", 
      count(distinct e.job_id) as "# of Jobs" 
    from departments d left join employees e 
      on d.department_id = e.department_id
    left join locations l 
      on l.location_id = e.location_id 
    group by d.Department_name, 
             substr(nvl(l.city,'Not Assigned Yet'), 1,25)
```